# CSS - positioning of overlapping div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need to create the following layout:
[image]
There is a container which holds all content of the site and the container needs to be centered in the browser window. The container has a non-fixed height as it needs to expand with the content. Inside the container there will be an other div holding the actual page contents.

Then to my problem, I need a special div which overlaps the left border of the container div as this will be a very special border (don't suggest using any of the css border properties).

It's okay to change the height of the overlapping div with Javascript (and you don't need to show me how). But I would like the positioning to be done in only html and css. I will be very grateful for all suggestions.

Comment: You will get faster help if you post the code you have come up with up to now, and a demo of that code on a website like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.  Also, please explain what's so special about your border that it can't be rendered as a border.

Comment: Div not a background?

Comment: When no code is shown, it comes across as you're just trying to get people to do your homework for you. No offense if that's not the case, but surely you can understand.

Comment: Thank you guys. I got an answer which should be enough for me to make it work. And it's very close to the code I was using, don't really now why I did not get it to work though. 

And yeah, I'm sorry for not posting my code. That was stupid of me, I'll keep that in mind until next time. And I do understand that it might seem like I'm trying to make someone do my homework. I'm mainly studying electronics and some computer technology now though so don't worry, you haven't helped me with any homework at all. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was bored, so decided to practice, Heres a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/o98hrd9o/3/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
      <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
          <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
          <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
          <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
          <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
          <p>  Hey I am the content</p>
    </div>  
    <div id="special">

    </div>

</div>

#container {background: orange;
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 10px 30px;
position:relative}

#content { background: brown}

#special {position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: -30px;
    width: 60px;
    background: red;
}


var height= $("#container").css("height");
height = height.replace("px","");
height = parseInt(height) + 20;

$("#special").css("height",height);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's quite similar to what I tried. Don't know why my code did not work. But I should be able to get it to work now though.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info.. but maybe something like this...

```
#overlap_div{
  position:absolute; z-index:9; left:0px, top: 0px;
}
```

and make the container of reference `position:relative`